# Blackfire failure "profile data is truncated"

Tags: php, memory, profiling, blackfire

At the moment I'm trying to analyze a PHP Application. The Profiler starts working and stops then at 1/10. While this the memory usage of the docker container goes straight up. After the failure in the blackfire log is an entry like "Profile data is trunctated."

I've tried to request it with curl over the cli and with firefox. If I call the page normally in Firefox or via curl I get the correct response

curl --request GET   --url 'http://xxx/index.php?eID=contacts&optigemId=1335600'   --header 'cookie: fe_typo_user=xxxx'   --cookie fe_typo_user=xxx

Comment: Ok I have analysed it a deeper. Now I get these Log Message from Blackfire: "Error while unmarshalling graph. EOF " and from curl "curl: (52) Empty reply from server"

Answer (score 2):

By chance, do you have any disabled PHP functions in your php.ini or any other PHP configuration file for your domain ? 
(`disable_functions` in php.ini, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions)

I had to delete the function `opcache_get_status` from the list of disabled functions to get Blackfire to work with my PHP configuration on Plesk.

Cheers.